# What is subsampling for a regression problem

Tags: regression, time-series

In the purpose of reducing the impact of excessive number of zeros inside a regression problem, someone suggested me to try subsampling the original data a bit, but I did not find any good source for subsampling data for a regression problem.

Could someone explain to me what is 'subsampling'? Is there an optimal way to subsampling?

**THE ORIGINAL PROBLEM**

```
ipdb> np.count_nonzero(test==0) / len(ytrue) * 100                                                                                          
76.44815766923736
```

I have a datafile counting `24000` prices where I use them for a time series forecasting problem. Instead of trying predicting the price, I tried to predict log-return, i.e. `log(P_t/P_P{t-1})`. I have applied the log-return over the prices as well as all the features. The prediction are not bad, but the trend tend to predict zero. As you can see above, `~76%` of the data are zeros.

[image]

That picture is probably the best prediction I have on the log-return, i.e `log(P_t/P_{t-1})`. Although it is not bad, the remaining predictions tend to predict zero. As you can see in the above question, there is too many zeros. I have probably the same problem inside the features as I take the log-return on the features as well, i.e. if `F` is a particular feature, then I apply `log(F_t/F_{t-1})`.

Here is a one day data, [log_return_with_features.pkl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mk5peBhHlluludUXynAQCW8NAQllbNpA/view?usp=sharing), with shape `(23369, 30, 161)`. Sorry, but I cannot tell what are the features. As I apply $\log(\frac{F_t}{F_{t-1}})$ on all the features and on the target (i.e. the price), then be aware I added 1e-8 to all the features before applying the log-return operation to avoid division by 0.

**P.S.** That project has on purpose "High-Frequency Trading".

Comment: The question needs details: What model, zero from which variable, what impact, etc. Without those it may be closed due to "unclear what you're asking."